# Triple integral volume problem

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, multiple-integral

I recently learned triple integrals. This is my first problem solving one with my own skills.

> Let $D$ be the region bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ and $x+y+z=1$. Compute
>   $$\iiint_D \frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{(x+y+z+1)^3}$$

So far I found the points where $x+y+z=1$ meets the $x$-, $y$- and $z$-axes: $$x=0,~y=0,~z=1  \text{ or } x=0,~z=0,~y=1 \text{ or } z=0,~y=0,~x=1$$

And this is the function I came up with,

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{1-(y+z)} \frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{(x+y+z+1)^3}$$

Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there something wrong with my limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your limits, both $y$ and $z$ can be simultaneously $1$, which is incorrect.

The correct limits are $0\le z \le 1$, $0 \le y \le 1-z$, and $0 \le x \le 1-y-z$. So you have to evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-z}\int_{0}^{1-y-z} \frac{1}{(x+y+z+1)^3}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

Comment: could you please explain where **1-z** comes from? this is my first time solving a problem like this so.

Comment: @user2511652 The idea is to ensure that $x+y+z \le 1 \implies x+y \le 1-z$. This problem becomes similar to $x+y \le a$. In that case, $0 \le y \le a$ and $0 \le x \le a-y$ are the limits of integration.

Comment: I see. So it's like a trick, I will try to use that idea in other problems. thank you

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a "trick" so much as a description of the geometry of the region. If you look at the region $D$ from a point far away on the $x$-axis, $D$ looks like a triangle on the $y,z$ plane with one edge on the line $y=0$, one edge on the line $z=0$, and one edge on the line $y=1-z$.

Answer (score 1):

The projection of the body on the $xy$-plane isn't $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Hint: what is $x + y + z = 1$ if $z = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

close

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-z}\int_0^{1-y-z} \frac {1}{(x+y+z+1)^3}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$